# Basic Types of Equilibrium Points at the Origin

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\Bbb{R}^2$. Put $T=\text{tr}A$ and $D=\text{det}A$. Show that if $0<D$ and $T>0$ then $\mathbf{0}$ is a source.

I know that the basic form of a characteristic polynomial is
\begin{align}
\lambda=\dfrac{(a+d)\pm\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)}}{2}=\dfrac{T\pm\sqrt{T^2-4D}}{2}
\end{align}

for a $2\times2$ matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  a&b\\
  c&d
\end{array}\right)$. For the origin to exhibit the characteristics of a source, the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}$ of $A$ needs to be of the form $\alpha\pm i\beta$ with $\alpha>0$. For this to be possible, I deduced that it must be necessary that $T^2-4D<0$. I am unsure on how to reach this inequality with just $T>0$ and $D>0$. I also found that $T>\sqrt{T^2-4D}$ in this particular case, but I don't think this helps much - am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Are you sure that I need complex conjugated unstable EV for a source?Wouldn't two with positive real parts be sufficient? Then you get that $T\pm\sqrt{T^2-4D}$ real and $>0$ if $0<4D\leq T^2$ and $T>0$, and the case for $4D>T^2$ you already have...

Comment: @NeitherNor Isn't a source defined to be having conjugated eigenvalues but with real part $\alpha_1=\alpha_2>0$? So that means $\sqrt{T^2-4D}$ must be imaginary then?

Comment: In my understanding, a source is only required to have 2 EV with positive real parts. These 2 EV do not necessarily have to be complex conjugated. In this case, I end up with the stated result, but you should read up how exactly a source is defined in your context.

Comment: @NeitherNor Sorry, my misunderstanding - a source is indeed represented by two real, distinct eigenvalues $\lambda>0$. But then you would need that $T^2<4D$ to hold, how would you arrive at that?

Comment: Are you now really sure that complex conjugated EV with positive real part are not allowed? I think you are going from one extreme to the other. IMO, the imag part of the EVs shouldn't matter _at all_, and a source is just something where all arrows point outwards, no matter if they spiral or not... but, as I said, I wouldn't be surprised if different authors use different definitions...